# Result appearing not as expected

Tags: matlab, return-value, pixel

I have the function listed at the bottom of this post which is supposed to return a matrix that has the same size of a matrix `x` with pixels that had a degree of membership `y`=1 to `1` and the other pixels to `0`.

But, when I ran the function I didn't get the expected results as follows (why is that?):

```
    >> x = [1 4 3; 6 4 3; 6 9 3; 2 4 3; 5 4 0; 5 3 1; 6 4 7];
    >> y = [0 0 1; 1 1 0; 1 1 0; 0 1 1; 0.2 0.8 0.54; 1 1 1; 0 0 0];

>> pixel_val(x,y)

ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
     0     0     0



        function c = pixel_val(x, y)
        [ii,jj]=find(y==1); 
        x(ii,jj)=1; 
        [ii2,jj2] = find (y~=1); 
        x(ii2,jj2)=0;   
        c = x;
        end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The indices `[ii, jj]` returned by `find` are not what you think they are.

You actually dont need two output arguments. Try this instead

```
ii      = find(y==1); 
x(ii)   = 1; 
ii      = find(y~=1); 
x(ii)   = 0;
```

Or, better yet, use logical indexing rather than `find` and do it in one line:

```
x(y==1) = 1;
x(y~=1) = 0;
```